# Autocomplete hover not responding properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created an Autocomplete component that rely on the selected value of the parent Autocomplete.

This working perfectly. When I type or hover in order to select then, both are working as expected.

```
const [hoverd, setHoverd] = useState(false);
const onMouseOver = () => setHoverd(true);
const onMouseOut = () => setHoverd(false);

  <div onMouseOver={onMouseOver} onMouseOut={onMouseOut}>
                <Card className={classes.paper} raised={hoverd}>
           <Grid item>
                        <Autocomplete
                            id="filter-by"
                            className={classes.search}
                            options={filterBy}
                            value={filterByValue}
                            onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                                setFilterByValue(newValue)
                            }}
                            renderInput={(params) =>
                                <TextField {...params}
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    label="Search by: ?"
                                    InputProps={{
                                        ...params.InputProps,
                                    }}
                                />}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    {filterByValue === 'Campaign' ? <Grid item>
                        <Autocomplete
                            id="filter-by-campaign"
                            className={classes.search}
                            options={campaignData}
                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.campaign}
                            renderInput={(params) =>
                                <TextField {...params}
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    label="Search by: campaign"
                                />}
                        />
                    </Grid> : <div />}
```

When I am moving the code to a separate component then its not working. I can type but the hover option not working.

```
{filterByValue === 'Campaign' ? <FilterByCampaign /> : <div />}

const FilterByCampaign = () => {
    return <Grid item>
        <Autocomplete
            id="filter-by-campaign"
            className={classes.search}
            options={campaignData}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.campaign}
            renderInput={(params) =>
                <TextField {...params}
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="Search by: campaign"
                />}
        />
    </Grid>
   }
```

I don’t understand what is the different between this two.

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: What is params in the first example? Maybe there’s an onMouseOver there?

Comment: Yes there is and when removing it its working (I update the code). How does the onMouseOver related to the Autocomplete ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try passing your onMouseOver function to the child component as a prop and then to the input

```js
{filterByValue === 'Campaign' ? <FilterByCampaign onMouseOver={onMouseOver} /> : <div />}

const FilterByCampaign = ({ onMouseOver }) => {
    return <Grid item>
        <Autocomplete
            id="filter-by-campaign"
            className={classes.search}
            options={campaignData}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.campaign}
            onMouseOver={onMouseOver} // depending on what the onMouseOver does either here
            renderInput={(params) =>
                <TextField 
                    {...params}
                    onMouseOver={onMouseOver} // or here
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="Search by: campaign"
                />}
        />
    </Grid>
   }
```

Comment: Apologize for the missing information. I am using the onMouseOver in order to raised the card component (I added the code).